# React Component don't emit event

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I can't make this simple react component to emit an event. I have an input field where I display the value to the DOM. This is what I got so far, I can't figure out the mistake, the console didn't log any error, that's why I'm so confused..

////Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const config = require('./webpack.config.js');
const compiler = webpack(config);
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(webpackMiddleware(compiler, {publicPath:config.output.publicPath}))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src'))

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('message', data => io.emit('message', data))
})

server.listen(3000, () => console.log('server is up!'))
```

///Main.js (the one that gets compiled to bundle.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import io from 'socket.io-client'
const socket = io()

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {val: ''}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        socket.on('message', data => this.setState({val: data}))
    }

    handle(e) {
        this.setState({val: e.target.value})
        socket.emit('message', e.target.value)
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <input onChange= {this.handle.bind(this)}/> <br />{this.state.val}
        </div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Any help or git that might help me figure it out would be helpful, ty!

Comment: const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

Comment: I wish it would'he been that easy..

Comment: maybe put it in the constructor instead ?

Comment: Documentation says that componentDidmount is the way to go, but I'll try in constructor as well, maybe it changes something..

Comment: i mean the socket = io ()

Comment: I don't think that's the main issue to be honest..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124442/discussion-between-razvan-alex-and-ayrton-dumas).

Comment: @AyrtonDumas no, connecting to io and having the socket object above the component is preferable in my opinion. OP I would check that a) your handle function is actually getting called, and b) put a log statement inside your server `connection` callback to make sure the client is actually making the connection